# Disabling code optimizations brings exceptions

Tags: windows, exception, visual-c++

I'm debugging some third party app in `Visual C++ 2019`. The default App configuration is set to full optimization (`Maximum Optimization (Favor Speed (/O2))`) and the project do compiles and run with no problems. BUT when I turn off the optimization (`Disabled (/Od)`) when I run the app I get some nasty `exceptions`!?

It's VERY weird. What can cause the problems when running the code without any optimizations?

Comment: The program exhibits undefined behavior. "Seems to work" and "throws exceptions" are two possible manifestations of undefined behavior.

Comment: @Igor Tandetnik Thx for a "great" response, very helpful! "The program exhibits undefined behavior." - yeah it's NOT a hard to see. Moreover I DIDN'T said that the program "Seems to work" - it's Yours words! It does work flawlessly for sure with optimizations enabled! Maybe instead of getting ultra general, just worthless answers You can try to say sth. useful...?

Comment: Well, ask ultra-general question, get ultra-general answer. The problem is somewhere in the code you haven't shown.  I, for one, cannot debug code I cannot see.

Answer (score 0):

> What can cause the problems when running the code without any optimizations?

This can be caused by what C++ standard calls [undefined behavior](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub).

The fact that the program does not run correctly without optimizations enabled is a proof that there is a bug in the code somewhere. Unfortunately, you haven't provided any code whatsoever to demonstrate the problem. We cannot even guess where the bug is.

Moreover, due to the nature of undefined behavior, the part of the source code where it eventually fails is not necessarily the part where the actual bug is. So, it order to find to root cause, it is necessary to consider the whole code base involved.

> when I run the app I get some nasty exceptions

What exceptions do you get and from where in the source code are those being thrown?

> It's VERY weird.

For professional C++ developers, such cases do not seem weird at all. So-called undefined behavior is an essential part of the C++ language. Unlike many other languages, in C++ there is no guarantee that if a code compiles and runs correctly that the program is actually correct. If you are not carefully following the best practices, the behavior you get might be just due to a chance. We see programs running with optimizations enabled but failing with debug builds (and vice versa) quite often.

Let's look at a couple of examples I've seen.

In some cases there was a lifetime issue, like taking a pointer to a temporary string object, and using it after the memory it is pointing to is no longer guaranteed to be allocated:

```
std::string func()
{
    std::string str{ "blah" };
    return str;
}

const char* p = func().c_str();
std::cout << p; // This is UB, because by this time, p is a stray pointer
```

This was working in release builds (by chance, because the memory `p` was pointing to just happened to still be around for some time). But in debug builds, it produced access violations (because the memory got already deallocated, perhaps due to some additional functions, e.g., debug checks, that happened to run in the string object's destructor in debug mode, I guess).

In other cases, it was an access of an array out of bounds:

```
int arr[3]{ 1, 2, 3 };
std::cout << arr[3]; // This is UB, because 3 is not a valid index for this array
```

This was working in release builds (by chance, because the memory region immediately adjacent to the `arr` array was allocated, although unused). But in debug builds, access violations ensued (probably due to more stringent checks, e.g., that of an out-of-bounds access, enforced in debug mode).

There are many, many other possibilities for bugs, of course.